Files in a Azure App Service local share are not accessible when using a public URL
I have a Azure App service (Linux) with a mounted local share from an Azure storage blob container. I followed the guide on this page. When I try to access a file in the local share via http, I get a HTTP ERROR 404. The url is https://cid-linux-storage.azurewebsites.net/media/naa.jpg.
The storage mount has the following properties;

In the SSH terminal, the storage mount is accessible.

The mount are also visible when browsing the site in Kudu.


Edited: App Service config
The blob container is set to an anonymous access level.
I applied a similar method using a Windows app service and a file share, and it was successful. For this site, I would prefer to adopt a Linux/Blob container approach.
My Linux skills are quite limited, and there might be a simple solution to my problem. I would appreciate any help.

You want to access the static files (image in your case) ?

Yes. I want to access static images (jpg's) in the /media folder.

You are uploading the images from portal or through the application?

How does your Program.cs file look?

Images are uploaded to the blob container from another Azure service. No program.cs, this will be a purely static website.

Ok..checking from my end..will let you know if I am able to access

I am unable to enable the basic option. Can you please share your App Service Configuration.

What is the Runtime Stack of your App Service?

I have added the App Service config above.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes, good idea.

Check the comments which I have shared in the Chat

Even I am unable to access the Images directly from the folder. I have even tried by uploading the images manually.
Check the below workaround to access Images ( or any static files) from the Subfolder which is in the wwwroot directory.

Create a sample .NET Core 8 Web Application.
In Program.cs, by default the app serves the Staticfiles, you can see UseStaticFiles.

I have taken references from MSDoc,
To access the files from the subfolder(media in your case), modify the code as below.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "media")),
    RequestPath = "/media"
});


Deploy the Web App to the same Azure Linux App Service where you have uploaded files.

Now you can access the files directly.


https://testapp29july.azurewebsites.net/media/foster-lake.jpg

Output:

